# Return reversed generic list-type in Java

Tags: java, list, generics, reverse

I'm doing some exercises on generic programming; is there a way to take a class that implements List and return a reversed version of that *same* class? It seems this should be feasible as this, at least taking the term at face value, is "generic programming" writ large.

Maybe by performing an in-place reversal? I also considered Collections.reverse(), but it's a void method.

Here is my attempt and demo:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ReverseDemo {

public static <T> List<T> reverse(List<T> list) {
    List<T> reversed = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reversed.add(list.get(i));
      }

    return reversed;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> linkedInt = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Double> arrayDouble = new ArrayList<Double>();

    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        double doubleNum = 10*Math.random();
        int intNum = (int) (10*Math.random());
        linkedInt.add(intNum);
        arrayDouble.add(doubleNum);
    }

    // LinkedList<Integer> demo
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(linkedInt.toArray()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reverse(linkedInt).toArray()));
    System.out.println(reverse(linkedInt) instanceof LinkedList<?>);  // false

    // ArrayList<Double> demo
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayDouble.toArray()));        
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reverse(arrayDouble).toArray()));          
System.out.println(reverse(arrayDouble) instanceof ArrayList<?>);  // true
}
}
```

Incidentally this is my first post here, does anyone know the best way to post code directly from Eclipse while preserving the spacing and indentation therefrom? I've used the four-spaces method specified here, but it's a bit inconsistent.

Comment: On your side question: while still in Eclipse, use Tab to indent more than the usual amount, and then just copy-paste. That's how I've been doing it since the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `java.util` implementations of `List` are cloneable, so you could use that, but sadly not without resorting to reflection. While on the reflection chapter, you may also use the copy-constructor, which is also sported by all Java's collections.

There is no fully general approach to non-destructive reversing, unfortunately.

Destructive reversing, on the other hand, is too trivial to be interesting.

Comment: You could also clone via serialization

Comment: You couldn't, actually: serialization, even if it succeeded, would give you a deep clone, which would not be the desired result.

Comment: What would be wrong with a deep clone?  I saw no such restriction in the OP.

Comment: Very much would be wrong. It is just not the expected semantics of the list reverse operation. Not to mention that it will fail if the complete object graph formed by the list, all its members, all their members, etc, contains just a single non-serializable instance.

Comment: True, my comment regarding serialization was not 100% qualified (i.e, all members of the object graph would have to be serializable), which was I didn't post it as a solution. I was merely commenting on another way of cloning (vs. reflection). Could you explain your comment `It is just not the expected semantics of the list reverse operation`, as I don't quite agree.  The OP is trying to write this operation, so how is soomething that's not written have unexpected semantics?

Comment: List reversal is a common enough operation to have an expected outcome, which is a list containing all the members of the original list, but in reverse order. Another way to phrase this expectation is that `reverse` is a *reversible* operation: `reverse o reverse = identity`.

Comment: Ok, I see now.  `Another way to phrase this expectation is that reverse is a reversible operation` - good explanation.

Comment: "All java.util implementations of List are cloneable" How does that help? `List` does not have a public `clone` method. So what do you propose to do? Use reflection to get the method from the specific class?

Comment: @newacct I propose exactly that, as clearly stated in the first sentence of my answer. Thank you for the downvote.

Answer (score 3):

The Guava library has a nice, non-destructive solution to the problem. See [Lists.reverse(List)](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Lists.java?name=refs/remotes/gcode-clone/coverage&r=29ab29c609537040d04f63f036c16889e32ec35a#725).

They define a suite of `ReverseList` classes that wrap the input `List`. From there, it's just a matter of translating all of calls (although "just" might be understating things a bit).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve the original list, you can try using:

```
originalList.getClass().newInstance()
```

That is not a 100% correct solution as it may throw if the original class does not have a default constructor. However, most collections have default constructors that create empty instances.

Answer (score 2):

try following

```
public static <T> List<T> reverse(List<T> list) {

    List<T> reversed=null;
    try {
        reversed = list.getClass().newInstance();
        Collections.reverse(list);
        reversed.addAll(list);

    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    };

     return reversed;
}
```

Comment: This will fail if the original List does not have a public constructor, such as `Arrays.asList(...)`

Answer (score 1):

The `Collections.reverse()` might be void, but that's only because you should be passing in the List to be reversed.

```
List<T> myList = ...;
Collections.reverse(myList);
```

You now have a reversed list.

Comment: Only, it is destructive. Making a non-destructive method is a challenge.

Comment: True, but it doesn't seem like the Op cares about that.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ReverseListDemo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<String> original = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
    List<String> reversal = reverse(original);

    System.out.println("Original: " + original);
    System.out.println("Reversal: " + reversal);
  }

  public static <T> List<T> reverse(List<T> list)
  {
    T[] objects = (T[]) list.toArray();
    List<T> copy = Arrays.asList(objects);
    Collections.reverse(copy);
    return copy;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I see that this particular code block works but when I tried it using my main method I get "false" when testing return types using instanceOf(). There is probably a "too academic" reason for this, or I'm missing the semantics of instanceOf(). Thank you for the constructive commentary.

Comment: The `reverse` method here returns a particular type of list (an internal class used by `Arrays.asList()`), not the same class as the input list as the OP wants.

Comment: I misunderstood the requirements. I thought OP wanted another List of the same genericized type.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies everyone. I wrote a method reverse2 which works at least for implementing classes ArrayList and LinkedList. Not sure how efficient it is.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Arrays;

// See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799066/return-reversed-generic-list-type-in-java.
public class ReverseDemo {

    public static <T> List<T> reverse1(List<T> list) {
        List<T> reversed = new ArrayList<T>();

        for (int i = list.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            reversed.add(list.get(i));
          }

        return reversed;
    }

    public static <T> List<T> reverse2(List<T> list) {
        int size = list.size();

        ArrayList<T> obArray = new ArrayList<T>();
        obArray.addAll(list);

        ListIterator<T> iter = list.listIterator();  
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            iter.next();
            iter.set(obArray.get(size - 1 - i));
        }       

        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> linkedInt = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Double> arrayDouble = new ArrayList<Double>();

        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            double doubleNum = 10*Math.random();
            int intNum = (int) (10*Math.random());
            linkedInt.add(intNum);
            arrayDouble.add(doubleNum);
        }

        TextIO.putln("Testing reverse1.");

        // LinkedList<Integer> demo
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(linkedInt.toArray()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reverse1(linkedInt).toArray()));
        TextIO.putln("LinkedList structure preserved?");
        System.out.println(reverse1(linkedInt) instanceof LinkedList<?>);

        // ArrayList<Double> demo
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayDouble.toArray()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reverse1(arrayDouble).toArray()));
        TextIO.putln("ArrayList structure preserved?");
        System.out.println(reverse1(arrayDouble) instanceof ArrayList<?>);

        TextIO.putln("\nTesting reverse2.");

        // LinkedList<Integer> demo
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(linkedInt.toArray()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reverse2(linkedInt).toArray()));
        TextIO.putln("LinkedList structure preserved?");
        System.out.println(reverse2(linkedInt) instanceof LinkedList<?>);

        // ArrayList<Double> demo
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayDouble.toArray()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reverse2(arrayDouble).toArray()));
        TextIO.putln("ArrayList structure preserved?");
        System.out.println(reverse2(arrayDouble) instanceof ArrayList<?>);
    }

}
```

console output:

Testing reverse1.
[8, 0, 1, 9, 3, 4, 3, 7, 6, 3]
[3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 3, 9, 1, 0, 8]
LinkedList structure preserved?
false
[8.301783107294664, 5.434068303620735, 9.095396759542615, 0.41823972682620836, 9.56659902304762, 3.2560723280079085, 4.037362000077436, 9.731919590391389, 0.5243645318825874, 5.9432185528462975]
[5.9432185528462975, 0.5243645318825874, 9.731919590391389, 4.037362000077436, 3.2560723280079085, 9.56659902304762, 0.41823972682620836, 9.095396759542615, 5.434068303620735, 8.301783107294664]
ArrayList structure preserved?
true

Testing reverse2.
[8, 0, 1, 9, 3, 4, 3, 7, 6, 3]
[3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 3, 9, 1, 0, 8]
LinkedList structure preserved?
true
[8.301783107294664, 5.434068303620735, 9.095396759542615, 0.41823972682620836, 9.56659902304762, 3.2560723280079085, 4.037362000077436, 9.731919590391389, 0.5243645318825874, 5.9432185528462975]
[5.9432185528462975, 0.5243645318825874, 9.731919590391389, 4.037362000077436, 3.2560723280079085, 9.56659902304762, 0.41823972682620836, 9.095396759542615, 5.434068303620735, 8.301783107294664]
ArrayList structure preserved?
true

Comment: `reverse2()` is destructive (it changes the original list object). If you're going to do that, why not just do `public static <T> List<T> reverse2(List<T> list) {
    Collections.reverse(list);
    return list;
}`

Comment: You are correct. There was no requirement for being non-destructive or destructive, but I see now that I was re-inventing the wheel.

Do you know why is generic non-destructive reversing so difficult to achieve?

Comment: because there is no general way to create another object of the same type